# Calculating member stress in a truss

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, structural-analysis, stresses

I have the following question:

[image]

[image]

Here is my attempt:

[image]

[image]

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in solving the reaction at joint "A". See calc below:

[image]

$\sum M_G = 0$

$R_A = \dfrac{22.31*8}{12} = 14.873$ kN

Solve internal member force using the method of section:

[image]

Since there is only one unknown in the vertical direction, so we can solve the member force $F_{BC}$ directly by $\sum F_X = 0$

$\sum F_X = 0$

$-F_{BC}cos 30^{o}$ + R_A = 0

$F_{BC} = \dfrac{R_A}{cos 30^{o}} = \dfrac{14.873}{0.866} = 17.17$ kN (Tension. Direction as assumed - away from the joint B)

$\sigma_{BC}$ = $\dfrac{17.17}{0.08} = 214.6 kN/m^2 = 214.6 kPa = 214,600 Pa$

Comment: Don't mean to criticize, but note, you need to improve the writing of numbers, **people must not need to GUESS what it is**. Sloppy writing can lead to confusion or costly mistakes, a big no-no for structural engineers.

Comment: Yes that’s true sorry about that

Comment: Glad to be helpful.